# java xpath how to get all data different of specific node

Tags: java, xpath, nodelist

I would like to get all nodes different of node car.

```
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        NodeList nodes = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("//car", document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

How to set something like :

```
NodeList nodes = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate(!"//car", document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an exclamation mark in front of the `XPath` string does not work. Indeed, for Java, the `XPath` expression is just a `String`: its content will not be interpreted by Java itself, but by the `XPath` library you are using.

Therefore, the only solution here is to modify the `XPath` expression *inside* the `String`.

You can do it as follows:

```java
NodeList nodes = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("//*[name() != 'car']", document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

**Explanation:** `//*[name() != 'car'` means : find all nodes in the document whose name is not `'car'`